# Solution of an Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots

I have this equation, and I want to find solution for x.

$\begin{align*}&(-2 x+2 α+1/(2 σ^2))\exp[(-(x-α)^2+(x-μ)/(2 σ^2))]+\\&(-2 x+2 β+1/(2σ^2))\exp[(-(x-β)^2+(x-μ)/(2 σ^2))]=0\end{align*}$

I have already used Wolfram, but it calculates the solution for $\sigma$, and other solvers say that they "Can not solve for x". Does anyone have an idea? Thank you all, in advance, for your concern.

P.S. Can I say that if this equation is equal to $0$, then only $(-2x+2 α+1/(2 σ^2))=0$ and $(-2 x+2 β+1/(2σ^2))=0$ **at the same time**, since exp is always $>0$.

Comment: It looks to me that you'd be hard-pressed to find a closed-form solution, given that you have polynomials of different degrees inside and outside the exponential...

Comment: @J.M. What do you think about my idea at (P.S.)? It's completely wrong?

Comment: According to Maple solution for $x$ is composed of [Lambert W functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: If you're sure everything is always real, then the P.S. ought to nail it, yes.

Comment: No, you cannot say the two polynomials are both $0$.  One could be positive and the other negative.

Comment: @RossMillikan ok you definitely have a point. Do you have any idea how i should proceed?

Comment: In fact, if we assume $\alpha \lt \beta$, \alpha+1/(4\sigma^2) \lt x \lt \beta+1/(4\sigma^2)$ (Otherwise just flip the inequalities).  This will allow numeric solution to proceed easily.  You could check out chapter 9 of http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html or any numerical analysis text.  Like the others, I don't think you will find an algebraic solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan The fact is, that i must find an algebraic solution for x, in any way, because i want to construct a rejection algorithm then.

Answer (score 1):

First a trivial algebraic simplification:
$$\begin{align}&{}\qquad (-2 x+2 α+1/(2 σ^2))\exp[(-(x-α)^2+(x-μ)/(2 σ^2))]\\
&{}\quad+(-2 x+2 β+1/(2σ^2))\exp[(-(x-β)^2+(x-μ)/(2 σ^2))] \\  \\
& = (-2 x+2 α+1/(2 σ^2))\exp[-(x-α)^2] \cdot \exp[(x-μ)/(2 σ^2)]\\
&{}\quad+(-2 x+2 β+1/(2σ^2))\exp[-(x-β)^2]\cdot\exp(x-μ)/(2 σ^2)],
\end{align}$$
so if this is $0$, then you can divide both sides by $\exp[(x-\mu)/(2\sigma^2)]$, since, as a value of the exponential function, that can never be $0$.

You have
$$
\left(-2(x-\alpha) + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right) \exp(-(x-\alpha)^2) + \left(-2(x-\beta) + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right) \exp(-(x-\beta)^2) = 0.
$$
A trivial substitution moves some complications into one place rather than two:
$$
\left(-2w + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right) \exp(-w^2) + \left(-2(w-\gamma) + \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right) \exp(-(w-\gamma)^2) = 0.
$$
At this point I ponder whether some other trivial simplifications might help.  E.g. you could cancel $\exp(-w^2)$ from both sides, and a few other things like that.  But those don't seem potentially fruitful.

So, I'm thinking maybe Newton--Raphson or the like.

**But: This looks like something that might have come from trying to find some MLEs.  So are you sure you shouldn't be trying to solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\sigma$ instead?**

Comment: i have to solve this for x, in any way, because this part is only a calculating part of my whole exercise, in order to find a rejection algorithm. I want the solution that verifies my equation, in order to use it to find an upper bound.